# regex causing logic error

Tags: java, regex

```
private final String reg2 = "[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]+@[a-z]+[.com|.net][.sg|.cn|.au]?";
```

this line of code is supposed to be the regex for an email tester. the current email I'm using to test it is Kenny@gmail.com(imaginary of course). However, it seems to be always wrong. How do I change it?

Comment: `"[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]+@[a-z]+(?:\\.com|\\.net)(?:\\.sg|\\.cn|\\.au)?"`

Comment: You seem to lack a basic understanding of regex (`[.com|.net]`). May I suggest you start with a tutorial?

Comment: "However, it seems to be always wrong" Your problem is obvious here, but in general, you can get better answers if you describe what you expect and what it does instead.

Answer (score 3):

It will be wrong because you are using character classes instead of alternative groups.

`(\.com|\.net)` - this is correct.

Your regex can match "Kenny@gmail.com" after a small enhancement ([see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/wX0fO2/2)):

`[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]+@[a-z]+(?:\.com|\.net)(?:\.sg|\.cn|\.au)?`

See more on [alternative lists here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and on [character classes here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: see he uses two charcater class not one. Don't combine the both.

Comment: It is just a sample to check "Kenny@gmail.com". But you are right. :)

Comment: I believe that he was intending to match e.g. `.com.au`, since that is a common domain in Australia, not `.com` or `.au`.